# Scan for hardware changes in Windows using command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line-interface

How can I scan for hardware changes in Windows using the command line? I'm looking for the same functionality as right-click "Scan for Hardware Changes" in the Device Manager.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get a copy of Microsoft's [`devcon`](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/182.how-to-obtain-the-current-version-of-device-console-utility-devcon-exe.aspx) utility.  Then use the following to [scan for new hardware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544746(v=vs.85).aspx#ddk_example_37_scan_the_computer_for_new_devices_tools):

```
devcon rescan
```

Answer (score 9):

It seems that Windows 10 ships with PnPUtil.exe. Run `pnputil.exe /scan-devices` from administrative command prompt to scan for hardware changes.

Create a batch file with the command. Create a shortcut to the file on Desktop by selecting "Send to Desktop" option from context menu (right click) of the file. Now you can change properties of the shortcut (shortcut -> Properties -> Advanced) to always run with administrative access.

This shortcut is easily available from Windows search. So, a Win button plus few keystrokes can do the job.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Does anyone know if there is also a PowerShell (or dotNET) equivalent for pnputil?